# Syntax error while using backslash in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I try to make simple `pipeline` on `Jenkins` to remove files from few directories time to time. I decided not to create `python` script with `Jenkinsfile` as new project, instead of it I try to define new `pipeline` script in `Jenkins` job.

```groovy
pipeline {

  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Check virtualenv') {
      steps {
          sh """
            rm -r /mnt/x/some/directory/Problem\ 1.0/path
          """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I got an error `WorkflowScript: 4: unexpected char: '\'`. How can I use path with whitespace on it without using backslash? Any other ideas how define path?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `'\'` character is a special character in Groovy. If you tried to compile this kind of code with the normal Groovy compiler, it would give you a better error message. The easiest way to handle it would be to escape it:

```groovy
"""
  rm -r /mnt/x/some/directory/Problem\\ 1.0/path
"""
```

Comment: For some reason that didn't work for me, it simply errored on the added '\'

Comment: Same issue i was facing with sed command where it needs space to be added while replacing. adding "\\" this fix the issue instead "\"

Comment: a backslash doesn't work so add more backslashes. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the shell command as follows:

```
      sh """
        rm -r /mnt/x/some/directory/Problem""" +  """ 1.0/path"""
```

Provide space before 1.0 as required. Hope this helps.

Comment: "lifesaver" shoutout